# How to return array using DOM getElementById

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, getelementbyid

### code.js(js file)

```js
let winter = ["applle","orange","grape"];
console.log(winter);
document.getElementById("fruits").innerHTML = winter;
```

```html
<h1 id="fruits">fruit stall</h1>
```

Why it's not working for me, can anyone help on this please...

I want array elements to be as output instead of "fruit stall"

Comment: Works as expected. Are you sure your JS file is in the correct location where it can be found?

Comment: Works for me. Firefox v113.0.2, Ubuntu v18.04.

Comment: when you try to access html element you should make sure the element is rendering.
so to solve this problem you should add your code on `windows.onload` event

```
window.onload = function() {
    let winter = ["applle","orange","grape"];
    console.log(winter);
    document.getElementById("fruits").innerHTML = winter;
};
```

Answer (score -3):

Your code works perfectly:

```js
let winter = ["applle", "orange", "grape"];
console.log(winter);
document.getElementById("fruits").innerHTML = winter;
```

```html
<h1 id="fruits"> fruit stall</h1>
```

Comment: So strange. It's working now. The file location was good. I did nothing and it started working now. Before I got this error: error code.js:326 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at code.js:326:46